# Obtaining outlier and collinearity diagnostics from the svyglm function in R

Tags: r

I am busy with a simulation study for my PhD where I am comparing output generated from ordinary least squares, weighted least squares and survey-weighted least squares regression applied to a stratified two-stage cluster sample.  I've used influence.measures(), vif() and colldiag() on the ordinary least squares and weighted least squares regressions, but cannot find a clear answer as to how the same diagnostics can be obtained for svyglm().  Can these measures be obtained in R and if so, how?

Comment: Is it not possible to contact the svyglm package authors on this?

Comment: I meant to give an update.  I did contact one of the authors that have published quite a bit of work on these measures.  Currently it is not possible to obtain these measures from an svyglm object, but he is working on a new package that will make it possible to obtain outlier and collinearity diagnostics based on the work he has published.  The package is not yet available on CRAN yet.